# How to auto-login in text mode?

Tags: 15.04, login, raspberrypi, auto-login, text-mode

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Ubuntu Mate 15.04. I've managed to make it boot in console mode, but now I want to enable auto login.

I already tried a lot of things, like:

- Editing /etc/inittab.
- Editing /etc/init/tty1.conf , from http://blog.shvetsov.com/2010/09/auto-login-ubuntu-user-from-cli.html.
- I also tried, as shown here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Automatic_login_to_virtual_console, editing /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf (and replacing username with "vitor"):

[Service]

ExecStart=

ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I 38400 linux

Nothing worked. I know there are similar questions here, but they are about older versions of Ubuntu and also didn't work.